# Google api javascript client sometimes works and sometimes is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api

I am using the Google API JavaScript client and encountering an error that I cannot figure out how to solve.

My HTML file has this script:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

And then the JavaScript looks like this:

```
function init() {
      window.initGapi();
}
(function() {
"use strict";
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', ['ui.bootstrap']);
appControllers.controller('MusicCtrl', function($window, $modal, $scope ) { 

        $scope.list = function() {

            gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                q: 'q',
                part: 'snippet'
            }).execute(function(response) {
                $scope.songs = response.result.items;
                $scope.$apply();            
            });     

        }

        $window.initGapi = function() {
            $scope.$apply($scope.load_youtube_api);
        }

        $scope.load_youtube_api = function() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey('API_KEY');
            gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                $scope.is_backend_ready = true;
                $scope.list();
            });
        }
```

And the `$scope.is_backend_ready` used the HTML to only load the markup for the `$scope.list()` only when the API has been loaded.

The error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: window.initGapi is not a function`. I notice this error occurs when I first load the page and if in the process of debugging I set a breakpoint on the `$scope.load_youtube_api` function, the API is loaded properly.

I dont't understand how the initilization function `window.initGapi();`, can, *sometimes and randomly*, be undefined when HTML should only load when the backend is ready. I got this code from the Google Developers website, so maybe I am implementing it wrong. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the function gets called before the script getting loaded, Keep $window.initGapi function inside $timeout and execute the function after a second.

Comment: I tried you suggestion, it did not work. Error message is still the same. I guess, my main question is, I do not think I am able to use a promises, as the Google Javascript client does not support promises, so how can 'wait' for load to finish?